# WSO2 Registry master-datasources.xml and WSO2AM_DB

Tags: wso2

The release 4.5.3 differs from the 4.5.1 in the sense that in the master-datasources.xml appears a new datasource for the WSO2AM_DB
What does this means?
How the two product relate to each other?
If I have a registry host and, API host and a MySQL host how can I have a shared registry?

As for what I configured before API manager was dependent from registry and BAM so I needed to have the DB for the registry and BAM (so install registry than BAM than API).

How do the new datasource change this dependancy path does Registry also be dependant on the API manager, but who creates the DB first?

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0):

This does not mean Governance Registry is dependent on Api Manager. This is a datasource defined for API manager to use if available to store it is runtime data. You can use the same WSO2_CARBON_DB if you need but then you need to do some configurations. So this is purely to store API related run-time data additionally to Carbon database. (JNDI lookup for this datasource happens from API manager).

Answer (score 0):

We configured WSO2_CARBON_DB datasource to point to our organization's Oracle database. GReg distribution includes specific scripts required to setup the data model.

In case we need to point WSO2AM_DB datasource to the same Oracle DB, we could not find any scripts or documentation for that.